# Testing angularjs es6 factories with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, jasmine

I have the following file: classAModel.js with the following code:

```
class classAModel{
constructor(model) {
    'ngInject';
    if (!model) return {};
    this.id = model.id;
    this.name = model.name;
    this.displayName = model.displayName;
}
}
export default classAModel;
```

This code is defined as a factory in another file: module.js:

```
import classAModelfrom './classAModel'
module.factory('ClassAModel', ClassAModel);
```

This code works perfectly when not in a testing context. It works using Webpack to create a bundle that is loaded and runs. So far so good. Now, the question is how do I test this class. Before I changed my code to es6 style, it used be a function and it worked. The test first loads the bundle, but when I try to inject the factory (again, same as before), I get an error: *Unknown provider: modelProvider <- model <- classAModel*. I can understand why he thinks there is a problem, but I can't understand how to fix it.

Moreover, I'm wondering if this is the correct way to work with the factory rather then create a factory method inside the class, that gets the model, and then create my object.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post your test code? Have you tried creating a mock instance for `model` and passing it along in the constructor?

Comment: The code falls when trying to inject classAModel - it doesn't get inside the inject part as it did before. I think an example for a factory that gets as a parameter some mock server response and how to initialize it will really help here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you've provided, here's a simple test case for testing your factory. Hope this is what you're looking for.

```
import classAModel from './classAModel'

let classAInstance;
describe('classAModel', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        modelInstance = new Model();
        classAInstance = new classAModel(modelInstance);
    });

    it('should have id provided by model', () => {
        expect(classAInstance.id).toBe(modelInstance.id);
    });
});
```